# How to get each Core data entry number in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[image]

[image]

I don't want to count total number of entries, but I want to count it one by one like 1,2,3,4,5,6...
The current code display me the total number of entries.

please help me to achieve my goal.

```
func count_diaries(){
    let fetchRequet = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "MyDiary_Entity")
    do{
        let count = try manger.context.count(for: fetchRequet)
        print(count)
    }catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

I write this function but can not call it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code as text inside a ```code block```

Comment: I solved just need to count from 1 instead of zero

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Something Like This,

```
    ForEach(filterResults) { dairy in

          if let index = filterResults.firstIndex(of : dairy) {
          //Wright Your Code Here, Just Giving Example here
                CoreDataView_Row(
                     no_dairies : index   
                )
          }
    }
```

Hope You found this useful.